# Problem in finding equivalent resistance

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

The question was the find the equivalent resistance of the circuit between A and B. I simplified the circuit as: The triangular circuit is electrically symmetrical along XX', YY' and ZZ'. Therefore A, B and C are equi-potent points. I thus reduced them to a single point. I am stuck here. How can current flow from A to B as they are equi-potent?

Comment: Decent handwriting but can you crop out the white space?

Comment: And label the individual resistors so we can talk about them.

Comment: FWIW, when you apply the stimulus between A and B, that doesn't follow your symmetry, so you can't count on that symmetry to maintain A, B, and C at equal potential.

Comment: @ThePhoton All the resistors have the same resistance r. What do you mean by apply the stimulus between A and B?

Comment: When we ask "what's the equivalent resistance between A and B?" it's the same as asking "If we apply a 1 A current source between A and B, how much voltage will it have to produce to drive 1 A?"

Comment: As for all resistors having the same value, that doesn't help. If I say "the resistor with value r is in parallel to all the other resistors", you won't know which one I mean.

Comment: @ThePhoton Please tell what is wrong with my approach. What do you mean by "when you apply the stimulus between A and B"

Comment: The stimulus is what you'd apply to measure the resistance. Since you're not applying it symmetrically, why do you think the symmetry of the circuit matters?

Comment: @ThePhoton I think that symmetry matters because it helps to simplify the circuit by helping to identify the equipotent points and by the way how can current flow between points with same potential with resistors in between?

Comment: If you apply (for example) 1 V between A and B, you can't at the same time assume (or by any means conclude) that A and B are at equal potential.

Comment: Why this question has negative votes??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very popular [Star Delta Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform) is very ubiquituous here. It can be useful to memorize it:

[image]

$$R_a=\frac{R_1R_2+R_2R_3+R_3R_1}{R_1}$$

Essentially, \$R_a\$ is the inverse of the \$R_1\$, by a number which depends on the whole setup.

Through this, and replacing every value with \$r\$, the resistance on the delta branch after the transformation is:

$$ r_{aux}=\frac{3r^2}{r}=3r$$

Hence the resistance of every delta branch are the original \$r\$ plus the \$3r\$ in parallel:

$$ r_{branch}=3r||r=\frac{3r^2}{3r+r}=\frac{3}{4}r$$

where the operator \$||\$ stands for the calculation of the parallel resistance from \$r_1\$ and \$r_2\$:

$$r_1||r_2=\frac{r_1r_2}{r_1+r_2}$$

So, the final result is suming two branches in series, plus one branch in parallel:

$$R_{AB}= (\frac{3}{4}r+\frac{3}{4}r)||\frac{3}{4}r=\frac{3}{2}r||\frac{3}{4}r=\frac{3}{2}r (1||1/2)=\frac{3}{2}r \frac{1/2}{3/2}$$

Finally:
$$R_{AB}= \frac{1}{2}r$$

Note that this requires to leave the C point open-circuited.

This calculation can be also done by converting everything to a delta, which will give a resistance of \$r_{aux}=\frac{1}{3}r\$ on the converted delta, a sum of \$r_{branch}=r||\frac{1}{3}r=\frac{1}{4}r\$ in the new complete branch, and then a final series of only two branches: \$\frac{1}{4}r+\frac{1}{4}r=\frac{1}{2}r\$, recovering the same result.

EDIT: 
The suggested method can be applied by supposing a 10A current flowing from A to B | or alternatively, by applying a 10V voltage over A and B. [image]

The variables are \$i_1\$,\$i_2\$ and\$i_3\$. Hence, the four loops voltage equations are:
$$
r(i_0-i_1)=10\\
r(i_1-i_0)+r(i_1-i_3)+r(i_1-i_2)=0\\
r(i_2-i_1)+r(i_2-i_3)+ri_2=0\\
r(i_3-i_1)+r(i_3)+r(i_3-i_2)=0
$$
with the matrix form:
$$
r[1 -1 0 0;-1 3 -1 -1; 0 -1 3 -1; 0 -1 -1 3][i_0;i_1;i_2;i_3]=[10;0;0;0]
$$
Which leads to the solution:
$$
i_0=\frac{1}{r}20, 
i_1=\frac{1}{r}10, 
i_2=\frac{1}{r}5, 
i_3=\frac{1}{r}5
$$
Hence we recover our previous results.
$$R_{AB}=v_0/i_0=\frac{10}{\frac{20}{r}}=\frac{r}{2}$$

Finally, this result is trivial. Once you realize that \$i_2=i_3\$ by symmetry, the node D is equipotential with C, the resistance through the ACB branch is the same than the ADB branch, and twice of the AB branch, and the total resistance is:
$$r(2||2||1)=r(\frac{4}{4}||1)=r(1||1)=\frac{r}{2}$$

Comment: Can you please tell what is wrong with my approach?

Comment: My friend, they are asking you the resistance from A to B. So if you unify A and B you are voiding the question. In that way you got the value \$R_{(ABC)D}=\frac{1}{3}r\$, not \$R_{AB}\$. That is, you are getting another equivalent resistance able to be obtained from the same network. There are other setups too, like \$R_{AD}\$,\$R_{(AB)(CD)}\$ and any other depending on how you interconnect the ports. They requested you only A to B, letting all others unconnected.

Comment: But still, how can we find the current between A and B if they are equipotent and have a resistance in between?

Comment: @MrAP How / why do you think (know) that A and B are equipotent?

Comment: @Tyler because the triangle is symmetrical along the axes which i have marked in the figure.

Comment: @MrAP Because something is symmetrical along some axis does not mean that it is (necessarily) equipotent.

Comment: That is why that conclusion safely arose only after solved the circuit :):)

Comment: @Tyler but there are plenty of Youtube tutorials which say that if a circuit is symmetrical along some axis then the distribution of current in both the symmetrical parts is the same and the equivalent (coinciding) points are then equipotent.

Comment: You only should apply that rule very carefully, because that can be really tricky to realize the symmetry without forgetting that circuits are graphs, not drawings :)

Answer (score 1):

When you ask, what's the equivalent resistance between A and B?, it's the same as asking, in order to drive 1 A through the circuit from A to B, how much voltage must be applied. So the circuit you're interested in can be re-drawn like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN7CoF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you find \$V_{AB}\$ with 1 A stimulus as shown, it is numerically equal to the equivalent resistance of the network between A and B, because \$V=IR\$.

Since you're not applying the stimulus symmetrically to A, B, and C, the symmetry you found doesn't help you answer this question about the circuit.

The re-drawn circuit should also helps you see a couple of quick simplifications that can be made to solve the problem:

1. R1 is in parallel with the combination of the rest of the resistors.
2. There are two nodes that *are* at equal potential, allowing you to remove one of the resistors from consideration. This is a well known trick for solving balanced bridge problems, that could also be described as a symmetry effect.

Answer (score 0):

ACBDA is a wheatstone bridge. Hence you can remove the CD wire. Then it's easy parallel combination.